# JW player video play option using Amazon S3 video URL

Tags: ruby-on-rails, amazon-s3, jwplayer

Am using JW player to play the video or audio. Before moving to S3 its works fine, after moved to Amazon s3 its not working, its giving error like ***Error loading media:file could not played*** before its works fine for me

Note: All my videos and audios are public in my Amazon s3

Here is my JW player configuration

**Before s3**

```
<script type="text/javascript">
        jwplayer("myElement").setup({
          file: "/videos/derbywire_2013-05-11_21_12_48__0000.mp4?1368306925",
          height: 350,
          width: 350
        });
</script>
```

**After s3**

```
<script type="text/javascript">
        jwplayer("myElement").setup({
          file: "http://s3.amazonaws.com/derbywire_production/system/videos/52/original/derbywire_2013-05-11_21_12_48__0000.mp4?1368306925",
          height: 350,
          width: 350
        });
</script>
```

Comment: Can you provide a link demonstrating both of these set ups?

Comment: @EthanLongTail, see this URL for my JW-Player with Amazon-S3 setup https://derbywire.com/videos/15, it will ask you to sign in. To get sign-in use the following credentials (email:pskumarsrec88@gmail.com & password:123456). After signed-in use the above URL. Please help me out from this.

Comment: I went to that link, and this video played fine - http://s3.amazonaws.com/derbywire_production/system/videos/15/original/Whoorli_2_Final-2.mp4?1360202039, however, I would recommend upgrading from 6.1 to 6.5 - http://account.longtailvideo.com/

Comment: @EthanLongTail Some time its playing but most of the browsers its not playing. Am checking with my chrome **Ubuntu browser**... How can i upgrade from 6.1 to 6.5. Can i use the same account or should i create new account. Suppose i used the same account to upgrade then how much i need to spent. Can you help me.

Comment: You just need to download the new copy on the same account from the link I provided.